# Array retrieval in HTML5 with the help of LocalStorage

Tags: arrays, html, local-storage

I have 1 entry in my local storage file
 `10/10/2014 19:23:34` (date and time) as a key and

```
{"entries":[{"name":"s","contact":"s","location":"s","email":"sweety@yahoo.com","detail":"s","f_name":"form1"}]}
```

(form field records) as value

so my question is how to get this array with separated parameters like `Name = s`, `Contact = s`, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't already parse your data you can parse it like this:

```
var json = localStorage.getItem('10/10/2014 19:23:34');

if (json) {
    var data = JSON.parse(json);

    if (data !== null) {
        // then you can try to do something with the data within it
        var entries = data.entries;

        for (var i = 0, l = entries.length; i < l; i++) {
            var entry = entries[i];
            console.log(entry.name, entry.contact, entry.location, entry.email);
        }
    }
}
```